# PHP form to array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am trying to figure out how to set up a form that will pass the information to an array. It's not for my users its for me. I want a form that I can enter the information in and it will post to an array on a different page. Is this even possible?

Comment: The answer is YES. Period.

Comment: when you use post it is an array. $_POST

Answer (score 2):

Of course, that's the PHP functionnality for forms..

Look at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_forms_-_the_basics) or [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

You can send a form with `method="GET"` or `method="POST"` and receive it with `$_POST` or `$_GET` (in the PHP).

Comment: Check out http://w3fools.com as well.